# How does publish profile set environment of app?

Tags: asp.net-core

Ok, so with a .net core app, if you set the environmentname in the publish profile, the docs here say it will set the app's environment
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/visual-studio-publish-profiles?view=aspnetcore-3.0

quote:
Include the  property in the publish profile (.pubxml) or project file to set the app's environment:

How exactly will it do that?  I thought that other than using visual studio, you had to set it at the machine level?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Include environment name in publish profile like below

```
<EnvironmentName>Development</EnvironmentName>
```

After publishing it results into ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT in web.config in published code

```
<environmentVariables>
      <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
</environmentVariables>
```

If you have created different appSettings for each enviornment then based on ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT from web.config, app uses respective app settings file for example **appsettings.Development.json** in this case